# Netbeans Toggling Read-only

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-7

I was working and somehow switched one of the files to read-only mode. The only indication of this that I can seem to find is that I am unable to save the file (manually or while committing updates through Subversion.)

I'm fairly certain that I tweaked some setting and didn't modify the file settings outside of Netbeans.

I might be missing something fairly obvious, but how do I change this back?

Comment: You sure the file permissions haven't changed?

Comment: You might try closing and re-opening Netbeans, I've had this specific issue before and restarting fixed it for me.

Comment: @CODe : The problem disappeared after I re-opened it. Hopefully it doesn't come up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close and re-open Netbeans, I've had this specific issue before and restarting the IDE fixed it for me.

Netbeans can be rather glitchy at times. When you come across a strange issue that you don't think you caused, always close and re-open. I've come across a few different issues that this actually fixed for me.

Answer (score 4):

If @CODe 's solution is not working try to change access permissions of the folder/file. In my mac I did same to get it fixed.

```
chmod -R 777 <folder/file path>
```